# is there a way to allow virtualbox always grab keyboard input for the guest?

Tags: virtualbox

I have win7 as host and Ubuntu 18.04 as guest.I need my discord app installed on guest to work with caps-lock key even when Ubuntu window not in focus.

Comment: This is not very clear. Please give more details.

Comment: I want my guest to react for caps lock key while it's not in focus (while I'm using fullscreen app on host, for example).

Comment: If you have an extra USB keyboard, you can connect it to a guest OS semi-directly. The term is "USB passthrough". The keyboard will disappear from the host, the guest will be able to read it regardless of window focus.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to give a negative answer, but it is impossible for the guest to intercept
an event on the host. This would be an **enormous** security hole if the guest
could break out of the VM.

However, the host can intercept this key, for example by using
[AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/), and do an action that can be seen
on the guest. For example, if you define a shared folder, the host could
write to it something that the guest can detect and do the desired action.